# Filter paginated list on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would Like to paginate and filter a list. But the problem is that I lose the view of the paginator element. It is gone when I filter a link like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item"  href="{{route('producto.index',['id' => $ssubcategoria->id_subcategoria_producto])}}">{{$ssubcategoria->nombre}}</a>
```

**Controller**:

```
  class ProductoController extends Controller {
    public function getIndex(Request $request){

        $queryUser = Producto::query();

        $queryUser->orderBy('nombre','asc');

        if($request->input('id')){
            $queryUser->where('id_sub_categoria_producto','=',$request->input('id'));

        }      
        $productosPaginados = $queryUser->paginate(5);

        return view('shop/index',  compact('productosPaginados', $productosPaginados));
    } .... }
```

**My route**:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'ProductoController@getIndex','as' => 'producto.index' ]);
```

**Paginator**:

```
{{ $productosPaginados->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

The problem is that I get invisible paginator. When I charge for the first time the page I can see the paginator. But when I click the link above this element then it disappears from the `HTML`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thats because when you click the link, you are visiting a view not the index page. So you should be using id?=1 in index page in order to retain the pagination.